# Post Deleted Answer?

Tags: discussion

The question below has an answer that was down-voted and then deleted by the owner.  I was going to post something similar to the deleted answer.  Would it be permissible to copy the deleted answer and post it as my own.  If so should I cite them as the source or not cite them to respect their privacy?

Or would proper protocol require me to create text of my own that says the same thing using my own words?

[Create a "barrier" (prevent parallel execution) in Oracle PL/SQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30774/create-a-barrier-prevent-parallel-execution-in-oracle-pl-sql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Odds are they deleted it for a reason. I often find that I've written an answer, hit submit, then found that I missed something obvious.

Write it in your own words, reread both, then post.